# Jquery working on first select box, but copied code doesn't work on second

Tags: jquery, ajax, function, select

I am using the following to pull records from my mysql database using ajax. It then works out the line totals for each by multiplying the `qty` box by the `priceeach`. The problem I'm having is the first select works, but the second one doesn't, and in the console I am getting the following error message:

```
  Uncaught ReferenceError: change is not defined on line 97
```

which is this line :

```
                    options += data[x]['priceeach']; 
                } // <-- This Line
                $('#priceeach1').text(options);
            });
        });
```

of this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#stock1').on('change', function (){
            $('#qty1').val('');
            $('#linetotal1').text('');
            var newValue1 = $.getJSON('select2.php', {stockID: $(this).val()}, function(data){
                var options = '';
                for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) { 
                    options += data[x]['priceeach']; 
                }
                $('#priceeach1').text(options);
            });
        });
        $('#qty1').on('keyup', function (){
            var qty1 = $("#qty1").val();
            var priceeach1 =  $("#priceeach1").html();
            var total=parseFloat(priceeach1)  * parseInt(qty1);
            $('#linetotal1').html(total);
        });

        $('#stock2').on('change', function (){
            $('#qty2').val('');
            $('#linetotal2').text('');
            var newValue2 = $.getJSON('select2.php', {stockID: $(this).val()}, function(data){
                var options = '';
                for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) { 
                    options += data[x]['priceeach']; 
                }
                $('#priceeach2').text(options);
            });
        });
        $('#qty2').on('keyup', function (){
            var qty2 = $("#qty2").val();
            var priceeach2 =  $("#priceeach2").html();
            var total2=parseFloat(priceeach2)  * parseInt(qty2);
            $('#linetotal2').html(total2);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Following is the PHP/HTML:

```
<select id="customer">
    <option>Please Select / Search For A Customer</option>
    <?php
        $sql = <<<SQL
            SELECT *
            FROM `customers`
            SQL;
        if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){ die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');}
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            if ($row['bussinessname'] == ''){$name = $row['title'].' '.$name = $row['firstname'].' '.$name = $row['surname'];}
            else {$name = $row['bussinessname'];}
            echo '<option value="'.$row['customerID'].'">'.$name.'</option>';
        }
        echo '</select>';
    ?>
<br>
<br>
<select id="vehicle">
    <option>Select A Customers Vehicle</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<div class="stock1">
    <select id="stock1">
        <option>Please Select / Search For Stock</option>
        <?php
            $sql2 = <<<SQL
                SELECT *
                FROM `stock`
                SQL;
            if(!$result2 = $db->query($sql2)){ die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');}
            while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()){
                $instock = $row2['numberofstock'] - $row2['numberofstocksold'];
                if ($row2['numberofstocksold'] >= $row2['numberofstock']){$stockinfo = '';}
                else {$stockinfo = $row2['make'].' '.$row2['model'].' - '.$row2['tyrewidth'].'/'.$row2['tyreprofile'].'/'.$row2['tyresize'].'/'.$row2['tyrespeed'].'/'.$row2['tyreload'].' - ('.$instock.' In Stock) - £'.$row2['priceeach'].' Each';}
                echo '<option value="'.$row2['stockID'].'">'.$stockinfo.'</option>';
            }
        ?>
    </select>   X
    <input style="width:40px;" type="text" name="qty1" id="qty1" />
    <span style="display:none;"  id="priceeach1"></span>
    - Line Total : &pound;<span id="linetotal1"></span>
</div>
<div class="stock2">
    <select id="stock2">
        <option>Please Select / Search For Stock</option>
        <?php
            $sql3 = <<<SQL
                SELECT *
                FROM `stock`
                SQL;
            if(!$result3 = $db->query($sql3)){ die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');}
            while($row3 = $result3->fetch_assoc()){
                $instock = $row3['numberofstock'] - $row3['numberofstocksold'];
                if ($row3['numberofstocksold'] >= $row3['numberofstock']){$stockinfo = '';}
                else {$stockinfo = $row3['make'].' '.$row3['model'].' - '.$row3['tyrewidth'].'/'.$row3['tyreprofile'].'/'.$row3['tyresize'].'/'.$row3['tyrespeed'].'/'.$row3['tyreload'].' - ('.$instock.' In Stock)';}
                echo '<option value="'.$row3['stockID'].'">'.$stockinfo.'</option>';
            }
        ?>
    </select>   X
    <input style="width:40px;" type="text" name="qty2" id="qty2" />
    <span style="display:none;"  id="priceeach2"></span>  - 
    Line Total : &pound;<span id="linetotal2"></span>   
</div>
<div class="stock3">
    <select id="stock3">
        <option>Please Select / Search For Stock</option>
        <?php
            $sql4 = <<<SQL
                SELECT *
                FROM `stock`
                SQL;
            if(!$result4 = $db->query($sql4)){ die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');}
            while($row4 = $result4->fetch_assoc()){
                $instock = $row4['numberofstock'] - $row4['numberofstocksold'];
                if ($row4['numberofstocksold'] >= $row4['numberofstock']){$stockinfo = '';}
                else {$stockinfo = $row4['make'].' '.$row4['model'].' - '.$row4['tyrewidth'].'/'.$row4['tyreprofile'].'/'.$row4['tyresize'].'/'.$row4['tyrespeed'].'/'.$row4['tyreload'].' - ('.$instock.' In Stock)';}
                echo '<option value="'.$row4['stockID'].'">'.$stockinfo.'</option>';
            }
        ?>
    </select>   X 
    <input style="width:40px;" type="text" name="qty3" id="qty3" />
    <span style="display:none;"  id="priceeach3"></span>  - 
    Line Total : &pound;<span id="linetotal3"></span>       
</div>
<div class="stock4">
    <select id="stock4">
        <option>Please Select / Search For Stock</option>
        <?php
            $sql5 = <<<SQL
                SELECT *
                FROM `stock`
                SQL;
            if(!$result5 = $db->query($sql5)){ die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');}
            while($row5 = $result5->fetch_assoc()){
                $instock = $row5['numberofstock'] - $row5['numberofstocksold'];
                if ($row5['numberofstocksold'] >= $row5['numberofstock']){$stockinfo = '';}
                else {$stockinfo = $row5['make'].' '.$row5['model'].' - '.$row5['tyrewidth'].'/'.$row5['tyreprofile'].'/'.$row5['tyresize'].'/'.$row5['tyrespeed'].'/'.$row5['tyreload'].' - ('.$instock.' In Stock)';}
                echo '<option value="'.$row5['stockID'].'">'.$stockinfo.'</option>';
            }
        ?>
    </select>   X 
    <input style="width:40px;" type="text" name="qty4" id="qty4" />
    <span style="display:none;"  id="priceeach4"></span>  - 
    Line Total : &pound;<span id="linetotal4"></span>       
</div>
<div class="stock5">
    <select id="stock5">
        <option>Please Select / Search For Stock</option>
        <?php
            $sql6 = <<<SQL
                SELECT *
                FROM `stock`
                SQL;
            if(!$result6 = $db->query($sql6)){ die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');}
            while($row6 = $result6->fetch_assoc()){
                $instock = $row6['numberofstock'] - $row6['numberofstocksold'];
                if ($row6['numberofstocksold'] >= $row6['numberofstock']){$stockinfo = '';}
                else {$stockinfo = $row6['make'].' '.$row6['model'].' - '.$row6['tyrewidth'].'/'.$row6['tyreprofile'].'/'.$row6['tyresize'].'/'.$row6['tyrespeed'].'/'.$row6['tyreload'].' - ('.$instock.' In Stock)';}
                echo '<option value="'.$row6['stockID'].'">'.$stockinfo.'</option>';
            }
        ?>
    </select>   X 
    <input style="width:40px;" type="text" name="qty5" id="qty5" />
    <span style="display:none;"  id="priceeach5"></span>  - 
    Line Total : &pound;<span id="linetotal5"></span>       
</div>
```

Comment: I suspect you're missing quotes around `change` somewhere. I don't see it in the code you posted, but it's probably in the real code.

Comment: Iv just been through the whole code using find and all changes have quotes.

Comment: Can you post a link to the site?

Comment: Wow, you really need to learn the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) principle.

Comment: Its running locally at the min

Comment: Yes I know I need to learn the DRY principle, im just not sure how to put it into one function.

Comment: There's no way the error is happening on the line you point to. Did you count the lines in the PHP or the HTML source?

Comment: The important thing to know when implementing DRY: Use arrays. Any time you have variables like `$foo1`, `$foo2` and so on, they should be an array that you loop over.

Comment: Since the error is happening in the browser, you need to use the line number in the resulting HTML. If you open up the browser's Developer Tools with F12, you can see the actual source line where the error occurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `$('#stock1')` (or perhaps `$('#stock2')`) object does not have the `change` method, which is limited to `<input>` elements, `<textarea>` boxes, and `<select>` elements.

(BTW, your code should really be refactored.  You have two nearly identical functions that could easily be reduced down to one.)

You might consider using the following refactored code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('select[id^="stock"]').on('change', function () {
        var index = this.id.replace('stock', '');
        $('#qty' + index).val('');
        $('#linetotal' + index).text('');
        $.getJSON('select2.php', {stockID: $(this).val()}, function (data) {
            var options = '',
                x;
            for (x = 0; x < data.length; x += 1) { 
                options += data[x].priceeach; 
            }
            $('#priceeach' + index).text(options);
        });
    });
    $('input[id^="qty"]').on('keyup', function () {
        var index = this.id.replace('qty', ''),
            qty = $(this).val(),
            priceeach =  $('#priceeach' + index).text(),
            total = parseFloat(priceeach) * parseInt(qty, 10);
        $('#linetotal' + index).text(total);
    });
});
```

Comment: It does though as #stock1 is a dropdown select menu, and so is #stock2, the calculations for stock 1 work, its just the same code copied into stock 2 dont.

Comment: Ok, I have added the whole script with html and all.

Comment: This would cause a different error, like `Object #<object> has no method 'change'`

Comment: @IainSimpson, I've refactored your code. I don't know if it will help with the particular problem you're having, but your code will be better for it.  Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the refactored code, but it no longer works now?

Comment: qty is a text box, priceeach is a span which contents has been fetched by ajax, linetotal is a span generated by multiplying qty by priceeach using jquery. priceeach is a decimal like 20.21 qty is a whole number like 2 and linetotal is a decimal like 41.23

Comment: Thanks !, I can actually see the code on one screen now, is a lot better !.

Comment: @IainSimpson, I've made another change that should work on all selects with id that start with 'stock' and inputs with id that start with 'qty', so that it shouldn't matter how many stock fields you have. Let me know if it works.